# In Stripe, which one is binding: the 'amount' on the Payment Element or the 'amount' on the PaymentIntent?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm following the Stripe scenario [Collect payment details before creating an Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred).

I'm using it because my users can choose from a set of 3 subscription plans, each of a different price, so I'd like to only create a PaymentIntent when it's known which plan has been chosen. This way I avoid having to update the amount on the Intent after each click changing the chosen plan.

However, the amount on the Intent is not the only one in play. I also had to previously specify an `amount` param when creating the Stripe Payment Element in JS, like this:

```
const options = {
  mode: 'payment',
  amount: 1000,
  currency: 'usd',
  appearance: {},
};
const elements = stripe.elements(options);
```

Here's roughly the code used to create the PaymentIntent in the backend:

```
$paymentIntent = $stripeClient->paymentIntents->create([
    'amount' => $chosenPlan->getPriceForStripe(),
    'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
    'currency' => 'usd'
]);
```

The code to connect these two entities is practically the same as in the aforementioned Stripe scenario [Collect payment details before creating an Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred) - in its section [5 Submit the payment to Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?platform=web&type=payment#submit-the-payment).

**Now, the question is: which amount is actually binding, the one used, the one charged - or do they have to be equal?**

From my experiments in dev environment it seems that the amount on the PaymentIntent is. In other words, I can leave the amount on the Payment Element unchanged, and Stripe without complaining charges whatever I specify on the Intent, even though the two are not equal. But is this official behavior? Is this documented somewhere? Should I still add code to update the amount on the Payment Element (`elements.update({amount: newAmount});`)?

Answer (score 1):

The one on the backend(the PaymentIntent) is what's actually charged. It is required to be that way since you can't trust the frontend, a user can open Chrome devtools and edit the Javascript to set any amount there, and you don't want that amount to be what's used.

The expectation would be that if you do update the amount of the PaymentIntent on the backend, you call https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/update so that the PaymentElement can reflect it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Your reasoning is obviously very sound. Still, the question lingers in my mind: will I possibly hit trouble, now or in the future, if I DON'T update the Payment Element?

Comment: Well the main concern would be customer confusion, and confusion can lead to support load and chargebacks/disputes ("why do I see $100 on my bank statement, the website said I was paying $80") moreso than any technical breakage

Comment: My Payment Element doesn't statically show anywhere any amount (neither the one provided in JS upon its creation nor the one from the PaymentIntent). And when 3D Secure authentication box comes up, it shows the amount from the PaymentIntent. So this doesn't seem to be a concern and I think my question still stands: will I possibly hit trouble, now or in the future, if I DON'T update the Payment Element?

Comment: It shows the PaymentElement amount in the popups from Apple and Google Pay, and might also show in other surfaces for various payment methods like redirects to things like iDEAL or stuff.